# Quickbooks overwrite data

Tags: php, quickbooks

I am using QuickBooks WebConnect SDK to import vendors from my website to desktop application of QuickBooks for new vendors it works just fine. But when i try to import a vendor from my website which already exist in QuickBooks it wont update the data. During importing it does not show any error!. Is there any way i can update the vendor if it already exist in Qucikbooks. 
For Example previously I imported vendor john at that time email address was not present in the website for john so it didn't saved any email address. Now the email address exists i want to update vendor on my quickbooks desktop.

below is my code for adding vendor

```
$xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <?qbxml version="10.0"?>
        <QBXML>
            <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">
                <VendorAddRq requestID="' . $requestID . '">
                    <VendorAdd>
                        <Name>' .trim($record->lastName).', '.trim($record->firstName).'</Name>
                        <CompanyName></CompanyName>
                        <FirstName>'.trim($record->firstName).'</FirstName>
                        <LastName>'.trim($record->lastName).'</LastName>
                        <VendorAddress>
                            <Addr1>'.trim($record->firstName).' '.trim($record->lastName).'</Addr1>
                            <Addr2>'.$address1.'</Addr2>
                            <Addr3>'.$address2.'</Addr3>
                            <City>'.$city.'</City>
                            <State>'.$stateName.'</State>
                            <PostalCode>'.$zip1.'</PostalCode>
                            <Country></Country>
                        </VendorAddress>
                        <Phone>'.$cell.'</Phone>
                        <AltPhone></AltPhone>
                        <Fax></Fax>
                        <Email>'.$record->notaryMail.'</Email>  
                        <VendorTaxIdent>'.$pay.'</VendorTaxIdent>
                        <IsVendorEligibleFor1099>true</IsVendorEligibleFor1099>
                    </VendorAdd>
                </VendorAddRq>
            </QBXMLMsgsRq>
        </QBXML>';
```

Answer (score 0):

> During importing it does not show any error!

QuickBooks *is* throwing an error -- your application is probably just ignoring it.

> Is there any way i can update the vendor if it already exist in Qucikbooks.

Do a `VendorMod` instead of a `VendorAdd`. You'll need the `ListID` and `EditSequence` of the vendor, so you'll have to do a `VendorQuery` first.

*If you need further help, post your code and/or qbXML requests so that we can actually help you.*

Comment: Thanks for response keith so we have have to update vendor one by one?

Comment: and do i need to add another application in webconnect in order to update all the existing vendors from database of my site?

Comment: You can update them one-by-one if you want, or qbXML does support batching multiple requests together as well. No, you don't need to add another application to the Web Connector.

Comment: could you please guide me how i can perform batch update using VendorMod ?

Comment: or if you can provide a sample code that will be great!

Comment: http://www.consolibyte.com/docs/index.php/QbXML_FAQ#How_can_I_send_more_than_one_request_at_once.3F